# Get Application developer name

Tags: android, list, google-play, installed-applications

I want to get the application developer name. Somebody please show me how I can get this.
i tried but only get with installed applications and their icon .
i want to display developer name

Answer (score 2):

to get a list of the installed applications installed do the following :

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

the  [CATEGORY_LAUNCHER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) means it should appear in the Launcher as a top-level application .

the [queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) Retrieve all activities that can be performed for the given intent.

**To get the developer name , there is no offical api from Google to do so.**

but there is an **UNoffical** Api that allows you to do so , check this [Android Market Api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps) and check the example provided in the link .

Please give me some feedback

Hope that Helps

Comment: hey hi
i got the installed app but i want to show the developer name

Comment: so you can get the installed applications ? but you want to get the developer name of the application ?

Comment: sorry i dont think there is a possible way to do that

Comment: i need like this..

Facebook..

        
by facebook, Inc.
6.0

Comment: **Official API**? Are you sure?

Comment: sorry i updated my answer