# How to get developer name programmatically of my published apps?

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

I have used "more" button in my apps so that when user clicks it, my all other apps could be open with developer name. I don't want to hard-code developer name. I want to get this pro-grammatically.

so that if i change my developer name in google play developer console , it should be automatically changed in all of my published apps.

Comment: may be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520928/get-application-developer-name

Comment: I have used "more" button in my apps so that when user clicks it, my all other apps could be open with developer name. I don't want to hardcode developer name. I want to get this programmatically.